# every 3 rows in a single column should be assigned to new 3 columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having a text file , need to parse every 3 rows and assign to new three columns using pandas/numpy from dataframe.

Example sample.txt looks like this

```
com.google.plugin.system.url:540 ,,, 
178745,,, 
Country ,,, 
23-DEC-13 03-FEB-14 ,,, 
com.google.plugin.system.url:540 ,,, 
178744,,, 
Responsible ID ,,, 
23-DEC-13 03-FEB-14 ,,, ,,,
com.google.plugin.system.url:540 ,,,
 178743,,, 
Development Group ,,, 
23-DEC-13 03-FEB-14
##############################################################
```

Expected Output should like this

```
Name                                   ID        case         Date 
com.google.plugin.system.url:540     178745     Country   23-DEC-13 03-FEB-14
com.google.plugin.system.url:540     178744  Responsible ID  23-DEC-13 03-FEB-14
com.google.plugin.system.url:540      178744  Development Group  23-DEC-13 03-FEB-14
```

Kindly help me out anyone.how to re-frame this from above dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick as long as your records are within 4 rows segments:

```
import pandas as pd

#set file name and full path
file = 'filename.txt'

#read in file without headers and add a dummy column, make sure you reset index and keep it as it'll be your data
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=['record']).reset_index(drop=False)
#keep only the needed data
df = df[['level_0']]

#create new dataframe by reading values to each column based on location and segement 
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':df['level_0'].iloc[::4].values, 'ID':df['level_0'].iloc[1::4].values, 'case':df['level_0'].iloc[2::4].values, 'Date':df['level_0'].iloc[3::4].values})
```

Comment: After passing to new_df  , getting follow error  **ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index**

Comment: The code works for the data sample you’ve provided. So i suspect the rest of your data is causing the issue. As to the error: the message says that if you are passing a scalar values then you have to pass an index. So you can either not use a scalar values but instead use lists for example, or keep the scalar values and just pass an index.